# Alternatives to aluminum capacitors

Tags: power, capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor

I am looking for an aluminum capacitor that doesn't exist. It has to be 600uF, 450V, but fit to height of 30-35mm and endure 10000 hours. Would be nice, if it could be rectangular. Ah, and cheap.

So the question is, is there other capacitor technology available for such requirements?

Comment: Rectangular ? Are you kidding ?

Comment: I wish i would... By the way, i once saw one rectangular, only it costed 200 dollars.

Comment: I am sure in quantities every manufacturer will build you something like that, isn't exactly rocket science.

Comment: Can't you use values from the E12 series ? 560µ or 680µ would be a lot easier to find. Also, can you put it horizontally ? I doubt you'll find such a cap with such a low height, but you may find one that has a 35mm diameter.

Comment: Quantities are not that high

Comment: Yes, 560uF or 680uF is fine. Even twice 330uF is OK

Comment: Then, ALC10A681DL450, in stock at mouser. 35mm diameter. 450V 680µ 15000 hours. I'm a master at shopping questions... Wait... Is that a shopping question ?

Comment: Mmmmm.. It's datasheet was already open. Now i wonder, what was wrong that i started searching for something else. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, it's 80mm high! That's too much...

Comment: Then fit it horizontally. In a rectangular box, if you must...

Comment: Yeah... But then it's additional assembly process.

Comment: Come on... Ok, ALC10A561DF450 is 35x50mm, for 560µF. That's my best bet.

Comment: Or three ALC10A221DC450 in parallel. That will actually be 35mm tall. Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with Kemet. Actually, I think you can easily find the equivalent from other manufacturers.

Comment: Not so easy by the way. But anyway i don't have space for three.

Comment: Ok, I give up...

Comment: So, other technology?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. But I'm not aware of everything (far from it). If there is another technology, however, I'd bet it would be more expensive than having this "additional assembly process" you were talking about.

Comment: With regards to your edit, you **are** looking for a specific product. A very specific one - you've even given full specifications of the product you need! You're question is a shopping question, and those are off topic.

Comment: I don't know what can be less specific. Jus for you: what capacitors are like alluminum, but not round and/or shorter. Not part number! Not manufacturer! Just a kind of capacitor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily cheap, but they have the form factor you need:

[Cornell-Dubilier electrolytics](http://www.cde.com/capacitors/aluminum-electrolytic)

They have different ranges for 5 and 10 year life.

Thickness of the MLP series is 0.5" (about 12.5mm) max.

I would note that these devices are widely used in high reliablity applications and have been around for many years and are expected to be around for many more.

Although some products can quickly become obsolete (a reason for the off-topic rule), this product line is not one of them.